# Not responding to touch event

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I tap on a button, or even a cell, any tap event, will take a while to load for the first time. Can any one tell me why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: please show us what your code.

Comment: mind to show some code for us to see what's causing the delay?

Comment: @ChristianAbella here is my code http://pastebin.com/b46zp8Aa

Comment: Adding code to the question would be most preferred. NOT using GIF would be nice, too. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the images, assets etc.. for your views takes a while, even on the quickest of devices.

Without having seen your code, I'm pretty sure that you haven't "preloaded" everything... That is, getting all the UIViewControllers, UIImages etc... all loaded into memory before the fact.

Singletons are handy for this.. Tough resource heavy, they get the job done..

Another option is to look at the NSCache, another handy class for quick access to data...

Without example code, it's hard to explain what the issue is...

Comment: Are you using segue's between your views? The reason I ask is that I notice that "popUpView" is manually set to hidden as opposed to you using a segue to its viewController.

Comment: The popUpView is not there anymore i have deleted the view and yes am using segue between them

Comment: You'll need to use GCD a little more as you're mixing fast processes like UI updates and slow processes like URL requests. Put the URL requests etc... dispatch_asynch (or dispatch_synch) the requests and large loops to a background queue, when the individual tasks are done, have them call back to the main thread to update the UI.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Without rewriting all the code it'll be difficult.. Maybe have a look at this simple 2 part article about GCD: https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1